# How to control the band equalizer

Tags: iphone, ios, audiounit, equalizer

Now I have some band:

> self.eqFrequencies= @[ @32, @500, @1000, @2000, @4000, @8000, @16000
>   ];

I want to do it like:

[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://a280.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/082/Purple/v4/44/50/51/44505125-6fc8-66a2-4dcd-ef02362db2ea/mzl.sbrtqwvv.320x480-75.jpg))</sub>

I know that `kAudioUnitSubType_NBandEQ`:(A generalized N-band graphic EQ with specifiable filter types per-band). I need the frequency is divided into Wave band (range, 20 - 16000), and then control the gain of each Wave band.